# Custom email address with Bootstrap

Tags: php, forms, email, field, registration

I have a registration form, with "Username", "Email", "Password" fields.
I would like that only email with "@mychoice.it" (it's only an example) can be used.

```
hitoeveryone@mychoice.it -> ok
erika@mychoice.it -> ok
anthony@gmail.it -> NO!!
```

It is possible? I'm using bootstrap and PHP.

This is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="registration.php" >

        <div class="form-group" id="form-login" >
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Indirizzo Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="nome.cognomeX@studio.unibo.it" name="Input_Email" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group"  id="form-login">
        <label for="exampleInputUsername1">Username</label> 
        <input type="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputUsername1" placeholder="username" name="Input_Username" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="form-login">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="example_InputPassword1" name="Input_Password" placeholder="password" required>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">Reset</button>
```

and this is my PHP script for registration

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['Input_Username'])) {
    $username = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Input_Username']);
}
if(isset($_POST['Input_Email'])) {
   $email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Input_Email']);
}
if(isset($_POST['Input_Password'])) {
    $password = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Input_Password']);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO utente (Email, Username, Password) VALUES ('$email', '$username', '$password')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$conn->close(); 
header("location:prova.php");  
?>
```

Comment: Sure, it's entirely possible. http://php.net/preg_match

Comment: Side note: You're missing any sort of validation of input data, and you should be hashing passwords with http://php.net/password_hash instead of storing them as plain-text.

Comment: yes I know, I'll add hasing password later ;)

Comment: why -2 valutation? :S

Comment: I don't know but I think that your question is interesting !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'connect.php';
$allowed_domains = array("example.com","example2.com");
if(isset($_POST['Input_Username'])) {
    $username = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Input_Username']);
}
if(isset($_POST['Input_Email'])) {
   $email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Input_Email']);
}
if(isset($_POST['Input_Password'])) {
$password = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Input_Password']);
}
$email = explode("@",$email);
if (in_array($email[1],$allowed_domains)) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO utente (Email, Username, Password) VALUES ('$email', '$username', '$password')";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $conn->close(); 
    header("location:prova.php");  
}else{
    DO SOMETHING ELSE HERE
}
?>
```